# Why is there a difference in analysis results in Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers CA2000

Tags: c#, idisposable, fxcop

My previous question was too abstract and downvoted. You can find it at [Factory method to create disposable containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214586/factory-method-to-create-disposable-containers)

I'd like to return two objects from a DAC factory. Namely the dataset loaded and the list of parameters used. There are two implementations abridged. Only one of them triggers CA2000. 
What is so special about Tuple vs POCO?

```
class Factory
{
    public Tuple<DataSet, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> CreateWrapped()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();//why does FxCop complains CA2000 here?
        var p = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        return Tuple.Create(ds, (IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>)p);
    }
    public PocoResult CreatePoco()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();//why does FxCop happy here?
        var p = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        return new PocoResult(ds, p);
    }
}
```

Below you see the POCO definition. In case you think it is important.

```
class PocoResult
{
    public PocoResult(DataSet dataSet, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> selectParameters)
    {
        DataSet = dataSet;
        SelectParameters = selectParameters;
    }
    public DataSet DataSet { get; }
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> SelectParameters { get; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there another rule that says `PocoResult` should implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: I don't know were to look for it. There is no any other entries in the Error List window. Using PocoDisposable leaves the analyzer happy too.